# scroll/drag the values with in the div when mouse down and moving

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need scroll-able div with mouse down event. For example refer this link: 
https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.ui.comp.sample.valuehelpdialog.example1/preview

If the selected values will overflow then we can scroll/drag the div we can see the others values too.

[Before Scroll Div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tU0Ky.png)
[image: After Scroll Div]

Comment: What do you mean draggable, I can't see it here: https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.ui.comp.sample.valuehelpdialog.example1/preview

Comment: Oh you mean the modal window?

Comment: In the input field some of the selected items are there.. in that area mouse down and move the mouse  to right... then u can see the values which are invisible

Comment: @JeroenBellemans am able to display the same. But am unable to scroll/drag div to see overflow values.

Comment: Oh, the div you provide screenshot is scrollable from left to right and vice versa, but it's not draggable. To make it scollable just set a fixed height and overflow-x/overflow-y property to scroll, as i did here below

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109917/discussion-between-anil-talla-and-m-k-wierzba).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
$(function () {
    $("#draggable").draggable();
});
```

```css
#draggable {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    padding: 0.5em;
}
.scrollable{
    overflow-y:scroll;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
    <div class="scrollable">
        <table id="t1">
            <tr class="item">
                <td>Item </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="item">
                <td>Item </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="item">
                <td>Item </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="item">
                <td>Item </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="item">
                <td>Item </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="item">
                <td>Item </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="item">
                <td>Item </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="item">
                <td>Item </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="item">
                <td>Item </td>

            </tr>
            <tr class="item">
                <td>Item </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```